# How to execute ruby script in production console from a file at my local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I have a file in my desktop called 'update_table.rb', a ruby block of code that goes through some tables and does some things. I want to run the ruby code directly in production rails console. I tried with - load '~/Desktop/update_table.rb' but load is looking for the file in the server. I don't want to upload the file to the server. Any help ?

Comment: What's a "production console"? Is this a Rails application?

Comment: Yes, it is rails application, sorry for not putting that there

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to upload the file to the server?

Answer (score 0):

'~/Desktop/update_table.rb'  - means - access file on the local machine in Desktop folder. But it's local in the context of the console! When you are on a server it's looking for a Desktop folder in the /home/your_username/Desktop on your server (not your laptop) which doesn't exist. This will NOT access your desktop on your client ( your laptop).

If you don't want to copy the file from your laptop  to your server, you could mount your laptop's filesystem on the server using various tools: samba, sshfs, nfs, etc - plenty of options there. However why just not copy file in the first place? Tasks like these - like maintaining data in a table -   are usually part of your app's rake rasks.